# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException spring boot 3.1.1 kotlin

Tags: linux, spring-boot, kotlin, deployment

i got error when build to jar file in server linux centos. But in local laptop is fine

the output error something like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.test.TestApplication

here is my pom.xml

```
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <mainClass>com.example.test.TestApplication</mainClass>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

i using spring boot 3.1.1, java 17 and kotlin 1.8.22

i already set my plugin, to TestApplication and TestApplicationKt, but still error, the java in server is using java version 20

`Maven home: /usr/share/maven Java version: 20.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /root/jdk-20.0.1`